# Listing category names in the legend

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I know this is a little outside of Kendo DataViz's intent but alas the client requested. I need my chart legend to consist of the category names instead of the series names. I has to be svg since this chart will be converted to a pdf later.
Here's a fiddle of what I have so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/JoelStransky/7QUt3/4/

```
function notsurewhyihavetoincludecode(){
return;
}
```

Comment: I notice that pie charts render exactly what I want. How do I get bar charts to render their legend this way? http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/pie-charts/pie-labels.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: So I kind of hacked (grotesquely) a way of doing this but it seems like there should be a simple config setting for this since pie charts clearly demonstrate its usage.
http://jsfiddle.net/JoelStransky/7QUt3/6/